# How to create a gradient

Tags: ios, linear-gradients

I have this code to create a gradient background

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.bounds;
UIColor *startColour = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#bcdef6"];
UIColor *endColour = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#fad7e6"];
UIColor *middleColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#ffffff"];

gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColour CGColor],(id)middleColor, (id)[endColour CGColor], nil];
gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0);
gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);
[self.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

how do i get rid of the greyish effect in the middle ?

this is the desired result:
[image]

this is the actual result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a bug with your colors array, you have not taken the CGColor of the middle color (white). By changing the array to this, I can get your desired result.

```
gradient.colors = @[(id)startColour.CGColor, (id)middleColor.CGColor, (id)endColour.CGColor];
```

By playing around with the gradient locations, you can also see more of the blue and pink colors should that create a better effect.

```
gradient.locations = @[@0.2f, @0.5f, @0.8f];
```

Comment: this indeed solves my problem. Can you explain the meaning of the "locations" array please ?

Comment: The locations are gradient stops, between 0.0 and 1.0, like a percentage over the distance of the gradient. So rather than starting to mix the blue and white between 0 and 50%, it only mixes between 20% and 50%, leaving the first 20% just blue. From the documentation "The gradient stops are specified as values between 0 and 1. The values must be monotonically increasing. If nil, the stops are spread uniformly across the range. Defaults to nil.

When rendered, the colors are mapped to the output color space before being interpolated."

Comment: I still don't understand? 0.2 means that the blue takes up 20% of the canvas from the left lower corner ?

Comment: Yes, at the left lower corner it will be blue, and only at 20% of the distance along the diagonal line will the blue start to mix with the white. By changing the gradient stops you can shorten or lengthen the distance that the colors mix. Change 0.2 to 0.4 and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: is it possible to change the angle of the white stripe ? for it not to go from top left corner to bottom right, but say top left corner + 20 pixels to bottom right corner -20 pixels ?

Comment: Not with a single linear gradient. That would be moving into custom drawing.

Comment: I fixed the angle with a 3d translate transform to the gradient layer, and making the layer a bit larger than the view it was to be set in